# Product of Lognormal PDF and Normal CDF

Tags: probability-distributions

For one of the engineering applications, we are required to calculate the integral of the product of a lognormal PDF and normal CDF. Essentially, the probablity of event occurance has a lognormal distribution, but once the event occurs, the probability of it to fail is normal. Hence, to compute the overall probability it is required to compute:

$\int \phi(x)\Phi(z) dx$,

where $\phi(x)$ = normal probability density function
$\Phi(z)$ = normal cumulative distribution function of z, where z is defined as:
$$
z = z_0 + a_0e^{bx}
$$
Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: do you know LATEX?

Comment: Yes, I do. The question has been type-setted correctly.